# Cascading Dictionary to Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, tuples

I have code that creates a data frame and a dictionary.  I attempt to cascade the dictionary's values to a new data frame column if the key appears in any row of the data frame, but I get an error.  See below for the code tried as well as the error message

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'key' : [['vs', 'vscode'] ['jupyter and jupyterlab', 'python'] ['python'], ['it was spyder before dawn']]})


my_dict = {'vscode' : 'is awesome', 
           'spyder' : 'is not so awesome, but hes ok, ig', 
           'vs' : 'is gross', 
           'same' : 'can fly'}

def cascade_col(row_value):
    cvc_row = []
    for word in row_value.split():
        if word in my_dict:
            cvc_row.append(my_dict[word])
    return cvc_row

df['dict value'] = df['key'].apply(cascade_col)
df
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Thank you for taking my question.

I tried to solve the issue but got an error message.  I clearly define the problem, my code, and the error message received.

Comment: Your initial problem and source of the TypeError is your input df, make sure to correct it before you continue and update the question if you still have problems.

Comment: Please post your input dataset and expected output in tabular form. That way it is easier to understand. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key' : [['vs', 'vscode'], ['jupyter and jupyterlab', 'python'], ['python'], ['it was spyder before dawn']]})

my_dict = {'vscode' : 'is awesome',
           'spyder' : 'is not so awesome, but hes ok, ig',
           'vs' : 'is gross',
           'same' : 'can fly'}

def cascade_col(row_value):
    cvc_row = []
    for word in row_value:
        if word in my_dict:
            cvc_row.append(my_dict[word])
    return cvc_row

df['dict value'] = df['key'].apply(cascade_col)

print(df)
```

Output

```
                                key              dict value
0                      [vs, vscode]  [is gross, is awesome]
1  [jupyter and jupyterlab, python]                      []
2                          [python]                      []
3       [it was spyder before dawn]                      []
```

1. There are no commas between lists in the dataframe.
2. You don't need to split() on row_value. split() is used to split a string into a list. You already have a list.